# String replace in Python, in sequence, by index

Tags: python, string, str-replace

I'm a newbie who just Started learning Python from YouTube. I am trying to make a program to replace old string Numbers with new string Numbers and facing problems while replacing numbers. Want to replace index-wise (What is its technical term (I don't know)). It can go in one direction or index-wise.

my string is `= (01010110110111011110111101111011110101101101101011011011010101010101010101011101110101110111101)`

and I want to replace 010 with 0, 0110, with 00, 01110, 000 and 011110 with 0000,

so my replaced string/output string will be like this..

```
(01 0011 0001111 00001111 00001 0011 001 0011 001 01 01 01 01 000111 0111 00001)
```

As per my code it's taking too much time (nearly more than 2-3 hourse for just 8MB file.

```
with open('1.txt', 'r') as f:
newstring = ''

old_list = ['010', '0110', '01110', '011110']
new_list = ['0', '00', '000', '0000']

while True:
    try:
        chunk = f.read()

    except:
        print('Error while file opening')
    if chunk:

        n = len(chunk)

        i = 0
        while i < n:
            flag = False
            for j in range(6, 2, -1):

                if chunk[i:i + j] in old_list:
                    flag = True
                    index = old_list.index(chunk[i:i + j])
                    newstring = newstring + new_list[index]

                    i = i + j

                    break
            if flag == False:
                    newstring = newstring + chunk[i]
                    i = i + 1
                    newstring=''.join((newstring))

        else:
            try:
                f = open('2xx.txt', "a")
                f.write("01"+newstring)
                f.close()

            except:
                print('Error While writing into file')

            break
```

Comment: So you don't replace on already replaced chars ?

Comment: There are some misconceptions here. When you open a file and call the file handle's read() function, you will receive a string (because you've opened the file implicitly in text mode) that represents the entire file content. You can then use the string's replace() function to achieve your objective. Having said that, your expected output doesn't fit your description because a) it contains spaces and b) the first 3 characters are 010 which you say should be replaced by 0. There are other anomalies too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
old_str = "01010110110111011110111101111011110101101101101011011011010101010101010101011101110101110111101"

split_str = old_str.split("0") # split by 0 delimiter
res = ""
for idx, each in enumerate(split_str):
    if idx % 2 != 0: # odd index, turn however many 1's into 0's
        res += "0" * len(each)
    else:
        res += each
print(res)
```

This is simple code, so it does not include any input validity checking, but it shows the basic concept. Edit accordingly to your situation/preferences

Comment: Respected Sir (ObjectJosh), as your Answer is absoulty Right, But when I have a String Like ,(001001001001001001001001001001001001001101100100110110011011001101011010011010110011011) and want to change to 101 into 01, 1001 into 01, 1101 into 011 and 11001 into 111. that time this code dont work. and this time I also want to go by index wise, It's kind request to you, please suggest me to the way to perfom task. or should I Ask another question, So at least you can win one more medal on this site.