# String Replace in python by index wise or by one direction from start to end

Tags: python, string, str-replace

I'm a newbie who just Started learning Python from YouTube. I am trying to make a program to replace old string Numbers with new string Numbers and facing problems while replacing numbers. Want to replace index-wise (What is its technical term (I don't know)). It can go in one direction or index-wise.

my string is = `(001001001001001001001001001001001001001101100100110110011011001101011010011010110011011)`

and I want to replace 101 with 01, 1101 with 11, 1001 with 011, and 11001 with 111,

so my replaced string/output string will be like this..
`(00011000110001100011000110001100110110011011010110101100110111011)` 
As per python's normal string replace method it Cant work Anyone can help my

```
string = "001001001001001001001001001001001001001101100100110110011011001101011010011010110011011"

string = string.replace('101', '01').replace('1101', '11').replace('1001', '011').replace('11001', '111')


fin.close()
fin = open("2x.txt", "wt")
fin.write(string)
fin.close()

(00011000110001100011000110001100110110011011010110101100110111011)
```

Comment: duplicate of your own question [String replace in Python, in sequence, by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70142080/string-replace-in-python-in-sequence-by-index) try to understand the answer that you accepted

Comment: The logic is not very clear

Answer (score 0):

In general python you can't "edit" strings, you need to create new ones. E.g:

```
my_old_string = '01010110110111011110111101111011110101101101101011011011010101010101010101011101110101110111101'

# use .replace()
my_new_string = my_old_string.replace('010', '0')
```

You could achieve the same thing with a single variable aswell:

```
string = '01010110110111011110111101111011110101101101101011011011010101010101010101011101110101110111101'

string = string.replace('010', '0')
string = string.replace('1101', '11')
# continue with this as often as you want
```

I am not sure, if your "doing all in one line" syntax is valid